# Jenkins inconsistency (file changes everytime)

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am new to Jenkins and still trying to understand how it actually works.

What I am trying to do is pretty simple. I trigger the build whenever I push it to my Github repo.

Then, I try to `ssh` into a server.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('SSH into the server') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
                    credentialsId: '<id>',
                    keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
                    sh '''
                    cd ~/.ssh
                    ls
                    cat ${KEY_FILE} > ./deployer_key.key
                    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
                    chmod 600 ./deployer_key.key
                    ssh-add ./deployer_key.key
                    ssh root@<my-server> ps -a
                    ssh-agent -k
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's literally a simple `ssh` task.

However, I am getting inconsistent results.

When I check the log,

**Failed Case**

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $KEY_FILE
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ cd /bms/home/pdsint/.ssh
+ ls
authorized_keys
known_hosts
known_hosts.old
+ cat ****
++ ssh-agent -s
+ eval 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-hb6yX48CJPQA/agent.51702;' export 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK;' 'SSH_AGENT_PID=51703;' export 'SSH_AGENT_PID;' echo Agent pid '51703;'
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-hb6yX48CJPQA/agent.51702
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=51703
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ echo Agent pid 51703
Agent pid 51703
+ chmod 600 ./deployer_key.key
+ ssh-add ./deployer_key.key
Identity added: ./deployer_key.key (./deployer_key.key)
+ ssh root@<my-server> docker ps -a
Host key verification failed.
```

When I `ls` inside the `.ssh` directory, it has those files.
In the success case,

**Success Case**

```
+ cd /bms/home/pdsint/.ssh
+ ls
authorized_keys
authorized_keys.bak <----------
known_hosts
known_hosts.old
+ cat ****
++ ssh-agent -s
+ eval 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yDNVe51565/agent.51565;' export 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK;' 'SSH_AGENT_PID=51566;' export 'SSH_AGENT_PID;' echo Agent pid '51566;'
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yDNVe51565/agent.51565
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=51566
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ echo Agent pid 51566
Agent pid 51566
+ chmod 600 ./deployer_key.key
+ ssh-add ./deployer_key.key
Identity added: ./deployer_key.key (./deployer_key.key)
+ ssh root@<my-server> docker ps -a
Warning: Permanently added '<my-server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

It has the `authorized_keys.bak` file.
I don't really think that file makes the difference, but all success logs have that file while all failure logs do not. Also, I really don't get why each build has different files in it. Aren't they supposed to be independent of each other? Isn't that the point of Jenkins (trying to build/test/deploy in a new environment)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your error is about matching host key (known_hosts file), not user key (authorized_keys). Investigate your known_hosts file to check if the key it contains matches the server.

Comment: the `known_hosts` file is generated in the Jenkins. Is there a way to investigate it and modify it if possible?

Comment: @raspy Also, what does the `known_host` need to contain? Is it the public key of the server that I am trying to access?

Comment: That's correct. It should contain a public key of the server. The message that you receive (`Host key verification failed.`) means that the key in the known_hosts file does not match key presented by the server.

Comment: @raspy so how am I supposed to do that if I am not able to `ssh` into the server in the first place? Do I just copy the server's public key (`id_rsa.pub`) can paste that into the Jenkins' `known_hosts`? Like `<the public key string> >> known_hosts`?

Comment: You can do `ssh-keyscan <myserver> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: BTW. I think your command may be simplified by just using `ssh -i ${KEY_FILE} root@<my-server> ps -a` instead of setting up ssh-agent.

Comment: @raspy You saved my life. It does exactly what I need! Thanks!!

Comment: `ssh -i ${KEY_FILE} root@<my-server> ps -a` I tried this one before but didn't work. Adding the `ssh-keyscan` did the trick.

Comment: Again, these are two different things. `ssh-keyscan` is required for updating `known_hosts`, `-i ${KEY_FILE}` provides a user key (instead of running `ssh-agent`). Both would be required to make it work.